# Using two semaphores in one method

Tags: c, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

I'm stuck on this assignment and I just can't get my head around it.

Let's say there's a queue of visitors waiting to get into one of the cars which are also queued. Only one car at a time is supposed to drive up to the platform to pick up 2 waiting people. As soon as 2 visitors enter the car it has to leave the platform.

I need to change the following methods "carArrives()" and "visitorArrives()" from Busy - Waiting to using either only Mutex or Semaphores.

Sorry for any mistakes.

```
int availableCars = 0;
int availableSeats = 0;


void carArrives(){
     while(availableCars > 0){noop;}   //exchange this with Mutex/Semaphore
     availableCars = 1;
     driveToPlatform();
     openDoors();
     availableSeats = 2;
     while(availableSeats > 0){noop;} //exchange this with Mutex/Semaphore
     closeDoors();
     leavePlatform();
     availableCars = 0;
}

void visitorArrives(){
     while(availableSeats < 1){noop;} //exchange this with Mutex/Semaphore
     enterCar();
     availableSeats = availableSeats - 1;

}
```

Comment: Great! I hope you will learn a lot by solving this. Do you have a question? Because I don't see any. Also "please do my homework" is not a question.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `while(availableCars > 0){noop;}`  This would be much better written as: `while(availableCars > 0){;}`

Comment: @user3629249, or even just use `;` without the curly braces `{}`.  But it should be supposed to use semaphores or mutex to do something... and then he never uses them.... 8-.

Answer (score 0):

if you generate a mutex:

```
pthread_mutex MyMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;
```

Then to stop any other part of the program from modifying some resource while the current thread is modifying/accessing the resource:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &MyMutex );
// modify or access resource here
pthread_mutex_unlock( &MyMutex );
```

Note:  to be effective, all places in the code that access that resource must use the same 'MyMutex'

regarding:

```
availableSeats = 2;
while(availableSeats > 0){noop;}
```

Suggest between locking a mutex for that same resource, to pause a bit, while not locked, to allow some other thread some time to modify the 'availableSeats' value.  For instance:

```
pthread_mutex SeatsFilled = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;
...
pthread_mutex_lock( &SeatsFilled );
availableSeats = 2;
pthread_mutex_unlock( &SeatsFilled );
...
do
{
    int numSeats;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &SeatsFilled );
    numSeats = availableSeats;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &SeatsFilled );

    if( !numSeats )
    {
        nanosleep( 1000 );
    }
} while( numSeats );
...
```